# Nullable reference types and "[CS8603] Possible null reference return."

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have almost successfully updated an library of mine to be "nullable aware". However the following code gives me trouble.

```
public static Result<string, TValid> ResultMustBe<TValid>
(
    this TValid self,
    params Func<TValid, Result<string, TValid>>[] validators
)
{
    var caller = new StackFrame(1)?.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.FullName ?? "?";

    if (!validators.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"No validators provided for EitherMustBe in {caller}");
    }

    Result<string, TValid>? result = null;

    foreach (var validator in validators)
    {
        try
        {
            result = validator(self);

            if (result is Result<string, TValid>.Invalid left)
            {
                return Result<string, TValid>.MakeInvalid(left.Error.Replace("<<caller>>", caller));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ValidationException($"Uncaught exception occured while validating {caller}", ex);
        }
    }
    // Warning produced here
    return result! as Result<string, TValid>.Valid;
}
```

```
public abstract class Result<TInvalid, TValid>
{
    public static Valid MakeValid(TValid data)
    {
        return new Valid(data);
    }

    public static Invalid MakeInvalid(TInvalid error)
    {
        return new Invalid(error);
    }

    public abstract bool IsValid { get; }

    public class Invalid : Result<TInvalid, TValid>
    {
        public TInvalid Error { get; }
        public override bool IsValid => false;

        public Invalid(TInvalid error)
        {
            Error = error;
        }
    }

    public class Valid : Result<TInvalid, TValid>
    {
        public TValid Data { get; }
        public override bool IsValid => true;

        public Valid(TValid data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me a warning for the **return** with `[CS8603] Possible null reference return` which I sort of can understand, seeing as I initialize `result` with `null`. However the method can never actually return null, `result` will always be the latest returned value from `validator`.

Is a `pragma warning diable` my only option here,  or am I missing something? I should add that I don't want to change the return type of my method Either (as again, it should be null-safe).

**Edit**: Renamed the class `Either` to `Result` (return type) as it distracted away from the question. Also included the code for the class. As asked in the comments the type was indeed inspired by FP, from Kotlin Arrow to be precise, but it was never intended to behave exactly like it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the complete warning you get from the compiler, including the line number.

Comment: Returned value will be null if you write code like this `1.EitherMustBe()` since your foreach will never execute. Compiler is absolutely right in warning about that.

Comment: @TanveerBadar As my comment said that can't happen. But I included the full code to show the check. However the problem is likely it is unable to pickup on that check.

Comment: But that's runtime, I am not sure how smart the compiler is. It might still be arriving at the same conclusion that I did even with the check.

Comment: @Index What is `Either`? If it is a class then your provided `Func<TValid, Either<string, TValid>>` can return `null`. Please [edit] your question to include the complete source code you have as a MCVE.

Comment: You can use [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving), if you sure, that null value isn't possible here

Comment: @Index C# doesn't have an Either type or discriminated unions. You'll have to post the code for this method. Typical implementations *don't* use `Left` and `Right` properties either, even in F#. They use pattern matching instead. Finally, `Either` shouldn't involve nulls, making the question's code specific to your `Either` and your implementation.

Comment: @Index what is this method trying to do? It seems like it returns the first failing result or the *last* valid value. Which, if `Either` works the way it should, would be identical to `Ok self` in F#, or `Either.MakeValid(self)` or whatever method you use to create a Valid result.

Comment: @Index the functional way to deal with call chains/pipelines is to pass the result of the previous call to the next, returning `Error` immediatelly if the input is an error itself. In F# you'd use `Fold`, in C# and LINQ, `Aggregate`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski "!" didn't work, thought it would. I've updated the question with your suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
// Warning produced here
return result! as Result<string, TValid>.Valid;
```

You are using the `as` operator, which can possibly return `null`, so the resulting type will be nullable. Use `as` when you think the type might *not* match and you want it to evaluate to `null` in cases that it doesn't. If you believe that it should always match, then use a regular cast.

```
return (Result<string, TValid>.Valid)result!;
```

This will throw if your assumption that `result` must be of type `Valid` is wrong, which is what you want. You might also want to add a `null` check to make sure you aren't somehow returning `null` (like if the last `validator` returned `null`.) (It's legal to cast a `null` value, so the cast will not catch it.)

Comment: Ah, of course - didn't think about implications of using the 'as' operator.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear even for functional programmers, because it contains no info on the Either type. Is it a custom class, does it come from a specific library? What is it's API?

C# doesn't have an Either type and F#, which does have discriminated unions and a [Result Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results) uses different syntax and in fact, only people that know a bit about Haskell may know that the *left* type is supposed to be the "error" value.

In any case, the functional way of chaining Results is for each function to receive the previous one's input and if it's an Error, return it immediately. If not, apply the function. This is often called [Railway oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/).

If you have a list/enumerable/array of functions (in this case validators), you can use `fold` in F# or LINQ's Aggregate in C# to call each validator and pass the previous result to it. Without knowing what Either looks like, or you can construct values for it, I can only propose a pseudocode example :

```
Either<string,TValue> ValidateEitherMustBe<TValid>
    (
        this TValid self,
        params Func<TValid, Either<string, TValid>>[] validators
    )
{
    var seed=Either<string, TValid>.MakeValid(self);
    var result=validators.Aggregate((previous,validator) => 
                       previous switch { Either<string, TValid>.Invalid _   => previous,
                                         Either<string, TValid>.Valid value => valid(value),
    });    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I really love unexplained downvotes weeks after the answer